# How can I use tech as a contract in defproc?

Tags: racket, scribble

Is it possible to have

```
@defproc[(foo) bar]{
  Blah blah
}
```

where `bar` is defined via `deftech` while linking to `bar` correctly?

Comment: This question on the Racket Users list might help: [_HtDP data definitions in Scribble_](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/J-x0C07b0V8/cRQRxam7NpYJ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! Use `#,`:

```
#lang scribble/manual

@defproc[(foo) #,(tech "bar")]{
  Blah blah
}

@section{What is bar?}

A @deftech{bar} is a baz.
```